# jQuery Raty - Reset a rating of another rating is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the jQuery Raty plugin and I would like to reset the rating on one of the lines that has been rated if the other one currently has a rating and vice versa. The two ratings are

```
$('#good').raty({
      iconRange: [['face-a.png', 1], ['face-b.png', 2], ['face-c.png', 3], ['face-d.png', 4], ['face-e.png', 5]],
      starOff:   'face-off.png',
      size:       35,
});

$('#bad').raty({
      iconRange: [['face-a.png', 1], ['face-b.png', 2], ['face-c.png', 3], ['face-d.png', 4], ['face-e.png', 5]],
      starOff:   'face-off.png',
      size:       35,
});
```

Anyone have experience on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For doing that you can follow the [Using directed actions with public functions](http://www.wbotelhos.com/raty/#action-demo) in the `raty` official documentation at http://www.wbotelhos.com/raty/

Hope it helps.